# What word is a good replacement for から used as "because" in informal speech?

Tags: grammar

What word should I use in informal speech for connecting cause and effect just like から does in polite form?

Comment: I hear から works pretty well when you're trying to capture the nuances of から

Comment: If you really want to be formal ため is more formal than から。

Comment: I suppose んで is more colloquial in places where you could use ので but it isn't exactly a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use から. It's not only used in "polite" speech (it doesn't actually matter what you mean by that), but also in "informal" speech.

If から reminds you too much of K/J-Pop, you can sometimes replace this から by ので/んで e.g.

> Xをするから => Xをするので

but you'll likely end up sounding *more* polite than when using から.

Comment: それから and　それで are not really synonyms and they don't exactly mean "because" either.  I'd say the former is more akin to "and then" and the latter more akin to "and so."

Comment: @emodendroket I was trying to say that many expressions using から (including the から meaning "because") can be replaced with expressions using で. I didn't claim that the result will always preserve meaning or nuance. In any case, my recommendation is to stick with から.